# How to run a sub-set of TestCases using --where for nunit

Tags: nunit, testcase, nunit-console

For my project I want to run the exact same test cases twice, once locally and on a different VM in parallel in the cloud (Azure in my case).

I duplicated the TestCase and tagged one `Category("Local")` and the other `Category("Cloud")`.
Running nunit3 from the console with `--where="cat == Cloud"` will thus run all TestCases of every test that has one or more TestCases tagged with `Category("Cloud")`.

Is there a different way of only running selected TestCases by a commandline switch?

Simplified example:

```
[TestCase(TestName = "Canary, Run in cloud."), Category("Cloud")]
[TestCase(TestName = "Canary, Run locally."), Category("Local")]
public void Canary()
{
    Assert.True(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a work-around.
Using `--params:Cloud=true` as command line argument and in the code

```
private bool ShallRunInCloud => TestContext.Parameters["Cloud"]?.ToLowerInvariant() == "true";
```